# What is the appropriate location of Azure Devops/TFS Release "support files" (Powershell, Configuration etc.)?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

On TFS 2018.2, I am building a release pipeline implying the use of :

- Applications configuration files
- PowerShell scripts
- HTML/Markdown templates (for release notes)

My applications configuration files are located on a net share for now and that works fine but I would like to version them later on.

I was about to store other files on my existing TFVC repository but I did not find a way to get them (with their directory) without adding the **entire** repository as a release input artifact.
I do not want to add them to my build artifacts since these files will be used for all my releases, no matter the applications I am building.

What is the recommended way

- to store these files
- to get them on release execution ?

I have been tempted to use the library but I feel this would be a misuse of it since it has been designed for secure files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution to this problem is something you've already hit upon: Add them to your build artifacts. In fact, it's better than pulling them from a separate repo for a very important reason:

**Your deployment scripts are going to evolve along with your application**. You lose the connection between "this version of the application was deployed with *these* particular scripts" if the scripts come from a separate location.

You have a lot of options to control the circumstances under which they get pubilshed/downloaded:

- You can use conditions on the publish artifacts tasks to control when they get published
- You can use artifact filters on the release definition to control when they get downloaded as part of a release

Comment: Agreed.  You really want your support files and documentation to be versioned with the code for compatibility.  For config files, if these are true XML/JSON config files, also consider tokenization in build process and token replacement in release process.